# How to hide/remove Shell ToolbarItems in child page?

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I defined some secondary `ToolbarItems`, that I want to see (mostly) everywhere, in the `AppShell` like this:

```
<Shell
 ...
>

    <Shell.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Test1" Order="Secondary" Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Test2" Order="Secondary" />
        <ToolbarItem Text="Test4" Order="Secondary" />
    </Shell.ToolbarItems>
...
</Shell>
```

But now, there are some pages, mostly at the end of the navigation tree, where I don't want to have these options, because they don't make sense there.

Is there a way, to remove or hide these ToolbarItems just on these individual pages?

Unfortunately, simply calling

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Shell.Current.ToolbarItems.Clear();
}
```

will remove them permanently.

Any ideas to accomplish them only for the current page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bindable `ToolBoxItem`,then you can control the visibility through a view model property.

I achieved this functionality, you refer to the following code.

1.create `BindableToolbarItem.cs` and add BindableProperty `IsVisible`.

```
public class BindableToolbarItem: ToolbarItem 
   {
       public static readonly BindableProperty IsVisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(BindableToolbarItem), true, BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnIsVisibleChanged);

       public bool IsVisible
       {
           get => (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty);
           set => SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value);
       }

       private static void OnIsVisibleChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
       {
           var item = bindable as BindableToolbarItem;

           if (item == null || item.Parent == null)
               return;

           //var toolbarItems = ((ContentPage)item.Parent).ToolbarItems;
           var toolbarItems = ((AppShell)item.Parent).ToolbarItems;

           if ((bool)newvalue && !toolbarItems.Contains(item))
           {
               MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                   toolbarItems.Add(item);
               });
           }
           else if (!(bool)newvalue && toolbarItems.Contains(item))
           {
              // Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { toolbarItems.Remove(item); });

               MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                   toolbarItems.Remove(item);
               });
           }
       }
   }
```

2.create a model to save different visible variables for different `ToolbarItem`.

```
public class TestVisibleModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private bool _isVisibl1;
        public bool IsVisible1
        {
            set{ SetProperty(ref _isVisibl1, value);}
            get { return _isVisibl1; }
        }

        private bool _isVisibl2;
        public bool IsVisible2
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _isVisibl2, value); }
            get { return _isVisibl2; }
        }

        private bool _isVisibl3;
        public bool IsVisible3
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref _isVisibl3, value); }
            get { return _isVisibl3; }
        }
        public TestVisibleModel() {
            IsVisible1 = true;
            IsVisible2 = true;
            IsVisible3 = true;
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

3.In `AppShell.xaml.cs`,define an instance for `TestVisibleModel` and bind the different variables to the `IsVisible` property of `ToolbarItem`  in `AppShell.xaml`.

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell 
{

    public TestVisibleModel visibleModel { get; private set; }

    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterRoutes();

        visibleModel = new TestVisibleModel();

        // Register a message in some module
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<VisibleChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
        {
            //DisplayAlert("Test", " receive...", "OK");
            visibleModel.IsVisible1 = m.Value.IsVisible1;
            visibleModel.IsVisible2 = m.Value.IsVisible2;
            visibleModel.IsVisible3 = m.Value.IsVisible3;
        });

        BindingContext = this;
        
    }

    void RegisterRoutes()
    {

    }
}
```

And in `AppShell.xaml`:

```
<Shell.ToolbarItems> 
    <local:BindableToolbarItem Text="Test1" Order="Secondary" Priority="0" x:Name="ToolbarItem1" IsVisible="{Binding visibleModel.IsVisible1}" />
    <local:BindableToolbarItem Text="Test2" Order="Secondary" x:Name="ToolbarItem2" IsVisible="{Binding visibleModel.IsVisible2}"/>
    <local:BindableToolbarItem Text="Test3" Order="Secondary" x:Name="ToolbarItem3" IsVisible="{Binding visibleModel.IsVisible3}"/>
</Shell.ToolbarItems>
```

4.In different pages, you can send message to `AppShell.xaml.cs` to change the value of different `IsVisible` variable.

```
 protected override void OnAppearing() 
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        TestVisibleModel model = new TestVisibleModel();
        model.IsVisible1 = false;
        model.IsVisible2 = false;
        model.IsVisible3 = true;

        // Send a message from some other module
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new VisibleChangedMessage(model));

    }
```

The code of `VisibleChangedMessage.cs`

```
 public class VisibleChangedMessage : ValueChangedMessage<TestVisibleModel> 
{
    public VisibleChangedMessage(TestVisibleModel value) : base(value)
    {

    }
}
```

Note:

For how to send message, please check document: [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).You need to install nuget `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that, although it look rather complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: Okay, tried it. I can "hide" (aka remove) the items on specific pages, BUT I cannot make them visible again when navigating back. The `onPropertyChanged` of the `BindableToolbarItem` is not called. I guess the objects get destroyed when removing them. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, `ToolbarItems` currently does not have an API to show or hide Items, we can only dynamically remove or add items.  You can only dynamically add or display items on each page. So, we need to send Message from different pages to `AppShell .xaml.cs` to change the value of the bind properties.

Comment: Okay, but how can we add the items again if the `onPropertyChanged` is not called, after removing the items?

Comment: So, we need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged `  for  `TestVisibleModel.cs` and call method `OnPropertyChanged` for each fields of `TestVisibleModel.cs`.  And if we want to add the `ToolbarItem`s, we need to set the value of several properties `IsVisible` of variable `visibleModel` in `AppShell.xaml.cs` to `true`.

Comment: Aaahh, now I get it. I have to set the visibility on the SAME instance of the TestavisibleModel.

Comment: Yes, we need to use the same instance of the view model (current is `TestVisibleModel.cs` ) of one page(current is `AppShell.xaml.cs`).

Comment: So, the idea is to pass around that model and inject it into the views, that need to show/hide the AppShell toolbar items. Correct? Not sure, if I like that approach, but that is for the team to decide. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, it is just the case. Hope that helps.